# Sybase database in cakephp connection

Tags: php, database, cakephp, sybase

This is my actual PHP connection

```
$connection = new PDO ('dblib:host=myhost';dbname=databasename, 'myuser', 'mypassword');
$connection ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

How could I declare it in CakePHP **app/Config/database.php**? there is any DataSource available?

Comment: 'driver' => 'sybase' or 'datasource' => 'Database/Sybase'   maybe?

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/datasources says that Database/Sybase is an incompatible datasource..

Answer (score 2):

1. Downlaod [SybaseDB](http://microsoft-sql-pdo-for-cakephp-2.x-master%20(1)) 0.3b to the app/Plugin folder.
2. Rename the folder **SybaseDB**
3. Enable the Plugin in your app/config/bootstrap.php file:

`CakePlugin::load('SybaseDB');`

If you are already using CakePlugin::loadAll(), then this step is not necessary.

4. Configure a database connection in app/Config/database.php file:

`public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'SybaseDB.Sybase',
        'host' => 'SERVERNAME',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'dbname',
    );`

5. Check your cakephp website.
   If the content show "CakePHP is able to connect to the database", it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

This is for CakePHP2

also place same file into /app/Model/Datasource/SybaseDB/Sybase.php

Otherwise gives error "Error: Datasource class Sybase could not be found."